# Customize a User's Signature

Tags: email

I'm running WordPress with CIVI 4.6.2, at some point in the set-up I managed to modify my personal email template to include my signature and logo. I am not using any extensions.

Currently my contact info and logo automatically appear in email messagew when I decide to email a contact through civicrm. Here's a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Unfortunately this modification only appears when I send emails. I have not been able to duplicate this modification for other users in the system. I cannot remember how I did this in the first place.

Any pointers on how I can accomplish this without installing an extension?

Thank you,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only edit the email signature when you open the full edit screen for your contact, not when you do an inline edit for email addresses.

- Go open the contact whose signature you want to set
- Click **Edit** at the top of the contact's record
- Then, scroll down and you'll see **Signature** below each email address.  You can set it there.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question but maybe intersting for many users:
We have developed an [extension that provides a set of features for using signatures in CiviCRM](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.signatures).

Please keep in mind that this extension is currently still in beta/dev stage and has an [issue when merging contacts](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.signatures/issues/1).